# How does Kevlar and Helmet Gear protect you?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

In *Counter-Strike: Global Offensive*, you can buy *Kevlar and Helmet* gear for $1000. This gear will protect you from enemy attacks. When you equip it, the number "100" appears next to your health: This is obviously an indicator of the integrity of your armor.

[image: The armor bar]

Over time, as you are hit by enemies, your gear will "wear out." The number (that indicates gear integrity) will be reduced every time you are hit, along with your health.

How does armor protect you? If my armor's integrity value is, say, 6, will it protect me just as much as armor with an integrity value of 100?
Or does the integrity value of the armor change how much the armor protects you?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Kevlar + Helmet:

- Reduces damage by a fixed percentage depending on the gun.
- Only applies when hit in the chest, stomach and arms for the kevlar.
- Only applies when hit in the head for the helmet.
- Legs do not receive the damage reduction from kevlar.

The way it works (explained using an example):

- The MP9 has a fixed damage reduction percentage of 50%.
- If no armour, at close range and hit in the stomach, the MP9 inflicts 32 points of health damage.
- With armour, if hit at the same range and place, the MP9 inflicts 16 points of health damage and 16 points of armour damage.
- With only 4 points of armour left, if hit at the same range and place, the MP9 inflicts 28 points of health damage and 4 points of armour damage. The full damage reduction is applied, but whatever can't be removed from points of armour is removed from health instead.
- Damage to both armour and HP is rounded before application. Health damage is rounded down and armour damage is rounded up.

Fixed damage reduction percentages for each gun can be found [here](http://counterstrike.wikia.com/wiki/Kevlar_+_Helmet).

My example gun damage was obtained from this [spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AjeX7SVcAzX2dDljYV9aWHJXN0VqX0hvOWJGNUM3d1E#gid=0).
An alternative I found is [here](http://kili.united-forum.de/cs/csgo_guntests.html). The numbers are slightly different from one another, however I do not know which is the more recent and I am unable to check myself at the moment.

Finally, I found a nice topic on the steam forums. It helped me with a few things I was unsure of. Take a read [here](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=3070590).

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the awesome answer. Now I know that when I have, for example, 99 armor points, I shouldn't spend $650 to replenish it.