# Counter Strike Bullets Registry

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive, counter-strike

I have seen couple of question regarding bullet registry in this forum but that did not help me.

These are the gameplay states for both CS 1.6 and CS GO:

- Server ping is stable between 20-30
- FPS is stable 100 for CS 1.6 and 170+ for CS GO
- Not much losses mostly 0 and sometimes fluctuate to 4-6
- Rates are 60 60 25k

Despite of all these for few servers I never get good bullet registry. Sometimes straight 4-5 hits with good rifle end up in just 88 or 90 dmg but no kill.

I noticed that servers can have different rates like 101 101 25k But **does rates effect bullet Registry**? **What else effects this registry**? (I already know recoil)

Comment: reason for down vote?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Server Tick rate is the main factor. Competitive MM is at 64Tick per second, while SOME private servers are at 128, the entire community cries in terror that Valve hasn't updated the servers with the proper rate.

The issue with this is, if you're spraying a gun, and the server is at 64T per second - it will only register so many of the shots, when the game and the server are talking 64 times per second. Now if you double that you get much more registered shots.

You can use

> sv_drawbulletimpacts 1

or

> sv_showimpacts 1

to view how your shots are hitting your target (can't remember if it requires sv_cheats 1 though).

I believe what you're asking is about damage and what affects it. Apart from recoil and hitting your target, there's also **damage falloff**, weather or not your target has **armor**, and where are you **hitting your target**.

If your target has armor you will, respectively, do less damage to them. So 90DMG per 5 hits might be normal. [This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5t1xoB_34E8) is a good armor video, also we 've talked about it [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/127219/how-does-kevlar-and-helmet-gear-protect-you).

The next thing that affects your weapons effectiveness is distance. Something like the AK is one tap HS at any distance BUT pretty much all of the SMGS are much more effective at close distance rather than battling with someone with AWP or even AK, they'll do much more damage to you at any distance.

The last thing on this list is where are you hitting your targets. Shot to the head with a MP9 at gunpoint would be a kill but to the leg you'd only do 19DMG

[THIS](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Y00On1PqBXvnO3kLvOoYsZihXJzBQkvae2XRkwADIv4/edit#gid=0) seams to be a great table for what I'm talking about. You can see different values for different distances and with or without armor.